# does ElasticSearch preserve disk storage when saving same value on same field

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I am sending log entries to ElasticSearch.  We are considering adding the calling method, calling class, and line of code to our log entries.  Being that these fields will contain similar values, would ElasticSearch attempt to preserve disk space by not copying this data for every occasion of the same value?

EDIT - Additional clarification:   I did not read anywhere that Elastic does this. I know that some data storage systems, like columnar databases, write their data to disk so as to preserve disk storage by not writing duplicated data over and over again.  So I am wondering if ElasticSearch implements similar techniques..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: no, it doesn't. It would make several key features quite hard I believe, and I have not seen any reference to this practice.

It's tricky to 'proof' the non-existence of some method unless you look at all source-code, but I would expect this page [about disk usage tuning](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/tune-for-disk-usage.html) to containt references to this practice.

Did you read anywhere about this, or does it just seem practical to you?

Comment: I will check out that link shortly.  To answer your question, no I did not read anywhere that Elastic does this.  I know that some data storage systems, like columnar databases, write their data to disk so as to preserve disk storage by not writing duplicated data over and over again.

Comment: @JoseMartinez did you find out more?